# Generating OpenSaml MetaData for a SP

Tags: java, cryptography, opensaml

I am attempting to implements SSO using SAML2, and my application is multi-tenant'ed and acting as a SP.  I am currently working on generating the SP metadata but I am a little stuck on the crypto side and can't seem to find any examples with the exception of what Stefan Rasmusson has put out there (I even bought his book), but none of it seems to cover the generation of metadata.  My question is, for the public keys included in the metadata, what is the best way to generate these.  Should I use my existing jks used to sign the rest of my messages, ie: authnrequests, etc, or should these keys be a separate, and should the key be unique for verifying signatures vs encrypting the data?  I am a bit lost, and haven't been able to find much documentation, so any help would be appreciated.    I have looked at this post: http://blog.samlsecurity.com/2012/02/generating-metadata-with-opensaml.html but it seems like he is generating the keys on the fly, which won't really work in a production.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a production, you certainly will not be generating keys on the fly. You have to register your SP metadata with the IDP so that would not easily work (unless the IDP is in your control).

It is allowed for the [SP to have two private keys](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPMultipleCredentials), one for signing and one for encryption/decryption, however this is not mandatory. Most production cases I have come across, the same key is used for both. I hope this helps.

It seems like you have Shibboleth SP setup already worked out, so rest of this answer may seem unnecessary. But for completeness, below are the steps to get a working Shibboleth SP.

- Get or build a private key store and certificate. This can be self-signed or from a CA
- Create a metadata file for the SP and register it with the federation. The  entry for "signing" and "encryption" sections will contain the certificate obtained in the previous step.
- Specify AssertionConsumerService urls for various SAML bindings that the SP will accept. The IDP will send back response to one of these urls

A sample SP metadata xml document would like below:

```
<md:EntityDescriptor entityID="https://mysp.example.com/shibboleth-sp" xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
    <md:SPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:protocol urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
        <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:KeyName>mysp.example.com</ds:KeyName>
                <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                REPLACE_ENTITY_ID_AND_ACS_URL_AND_PUT_YOUR_CERTIFICATE_HERE
            </ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </md:KeyDescriptor>
        <md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:KeyName>mysp.example.com</ds:KeyName>
                <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                REPLACE_ENTITY_ID_AND_ACS_URL_AND_PUT_YOUR_CERTIFICATE_HERE
            </ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </md:KeyDescriptor>
        <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://mysp.example.com/shibboleth/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST" index="1"/>
        <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact" Location="http://mysp.example.com/shibboleth/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/Artifact" index="2"/>
        <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:artifact-01" Location="http://mysp.example.com/shibboleth/Shibboleth.sso/SAML/Artifact" index="3"/>
        <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:browser-post" Location="http://mysp.example.com/shibboleth/Shibboleth.sso/SAML/POST" index="4"/>
    </md:SPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```